# How do I view MTM Test Run comments beyond Run Test screen?

Tags: microsoft-test-manager, mtm

sorry.  Seems like an easy question where once again I am missing something simple.

So...in the Run Tests screen I added a comment (same thing happens for screenshot) to the first step listed and passed it as successful.  If I Save and Close and go to the Plan tab/TestCase screen, actually nothing shows that the comment was created at all.  Same if I try to view it in the Run Test screen again.  It just disappears.  How do I keep it from disappearing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how it's done in MTM 2012:

1. Navigate to the **Test** tab.
2. Click **Analyze Test Runs**.
3. Open the desired **Test Run**.

   - Expand the **Tests** section if it's not already expanded.
4. Select desired results row and choose **View Results**.

   - Select the desired **Iteration** if more than one exists.

Your comment(s) should be visible in the results displayed.